# Why scipy.savetxt('filename', (x,y)) saves arrays by row instead of columns?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Most of csv files I have seen stores arrays like this:

```
#x y
0 10
1 11
2 12
 .
 .
 .
```

So, why `scipy.savetxt('scipy.txt', (x, y), header='x y', fmt='%g')` will store `x, y` like this:

```
# x y
0 1 2 3 4 5
10 11 12 13 14 15
```

While `scipy.savetxt('y.txt', y, header='y', fmt='%g')` will give:

```
# y
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

?

I have to use `scipy.savetxt('common.txt', scipy.column_stack((x,y)), header='x y', fmt='%g')` to obtain the more "common" format.

Note that to read `x` and `y` from "common" file:

`x, y = scipy.genfromtxt('common.txt', unpack=True)`

```
xy = scipy.genfromtxt('common.txt')
x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]

xy = scipy.genfromtxt('common.txt', names=True)
x = xy['x']
y = xy['y']
```

or even:

```
xy = scipy.genfromtxt('common.txt', names=True)
x, y = zip(*xy)
x, y = scipy.array(x), scipy.array(y)
```

From "scipy" file:

`x, y = scipy.genfromtxt('scipy.txt')`

While:

```
xy = scipy.genfromtxt('test.txt', names=True)
```

will raise an error, so we can't use header (anyway, does this header have a real meaning?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.savetxt` writes 1-dimensional arrays with one element per line.

`np.savetxt` writes 2-dimensional arrays with one row per line.

This explains why `scipy.savetxt('y.txt', y...)` gives you one long column. Also, numpy/scipy considers `(x, y)` to be a 1-dimensional tuple, not a 2-dimensional array. This is why you get

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
10 11 12 13 14 15
```

for output.

So, to get the desired output, pass a 2-dimensional array. Using `np.column_stack`, as you noted, is probably the easiest way:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt(filename, np.column_stack((x,y)), fmt='%g')
```

To read the data back into `x` and `y` variables, use the `unpack=True` parameter:

```
x, y = np.genfromtxt(filename, unpack=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that you're saving a (2,N), you really want a (N,2) array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
y = x + 2
print (x,y).shape
#(2,10)
z = np.array(zip(x,y))
print z.shape
#(10,2)
```

Or use a structured array for headers

```
z = np.array(zip(x,y),dtype=[('x',int),('y',float)])
print z.shape
#(10,)
np.savetxt('tmp.txt',z)
```

This gives what you expect.